# Search the ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, cursor, simplecursoradapter

Here is my Custom Adapter :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);


    Cursor cursbbn  = getCursor();



    if (row == null)

    {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) localContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listtype, null);
    }


    String Title = cursbbn.getString(2);
    String Readyin = cursbbn.getString(4);
    String Faovoites=cursbbn.getString(8);


    TextView titler=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.listmaintitle);
    TextView readyinr=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.listreadyin);

     int colorPos = position % colors.length;
     row.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);

    titler.setText(Title);
    readyinr.setText(Readyin);

    ImageView picture = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Bitmap bitImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(localContext.getResources(), R.drawable.seafood);

    if(Title.contentEquals("Fajita Raps"))
        picture.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerImage(bitImg));


    if (Faovoites.contentEquals("YES")) {

        ImageView star = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.favoritesicon);
        star.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    return row;
}
```

And This is my Search Edittext aftertextchanged event

```
public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {

            final String[] columns = new String[] {

            "_id", COL_SanID, COL_SanTitle, COL_SanCat, COL_SanReadyin,

            COL_SandServing, COL_SandIngred, COL_SandDirect, COL_SandFavor };

            Bundle extrass = getIntent().getExtras();

            final String Type = extrass.getString("CategoryType");

            mAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
                public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {

                    String value = "%" + constraint + "%";
                    String Type2 = "%" + Type + "%";

                    curs = mDb.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, COL_SanTitle
                            + " LIKE ? And " + COL_SanCat + " LIKE ?",
                            new String[] { value, Type2 }, null, null,
                            COL_SanTitle + " ASC");

                    return curs;

                }
            });
```

and Finally : Logcat exceptions

> 04-26 18:56:50.310: E/AndroidRuntime(878): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-26 18:56:50.310: E/AndroidRuntime(878): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
>   04-26 18:56:50.310: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
>   04-26 18:56:50.310: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
>   04-26 18:56:50.310: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
>   04-26 18:56:50.310: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at master.chef.mediamaster.Interface.onItemClick(Interface.java:781)
>   04-26 18:56:50.310: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
>   04-26 18:56:50.310: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
>   04-26 18:56:50.310: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
>   04-26 18:56:50.310: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>   04-26 18:56:50.310: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   04-26 18:56:50.310: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   04-26 18:56:50.310: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
>   04-26 18:56:50.310: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   04-26 18:56:50.310: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   04-26 18:56:50.310: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   04-26 18:56:50.310: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>   04-26 18:56:50.310: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: What is `mDb` and where do you declare it? Maybe we need to see also all the places you use it.

Comment: i declare the mDb database in the main activity at the same class SQLiteDatabase mDb; and also MyDbHelper mHelper to create the database table and define the columns. I think the problem is not in the database as it retrieves the values correctly and also i can search the views in case the custom cursoradapter is not defined. When i add the first line of the custom adapter (which is move to the cursor position)it gives me this error. Please let me know if you need more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `getView()` when you call `localCursor.moveToPosition(position);` you get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery`.

Why this happens? Because once filtering has been applied to the list view, the old cursor is closed and the new one is used instead. You can get the current underlying cursor by calling `getCursor()` instead of tracking the initial one. Get rid of `Cursor localCursor` and use `getCursor()` instead.

Comment: Thanks Arhimed for your answer , it makes sense , I've tried it but it gives me an error as well but may be i implemented it wrong as i am newbie to the development.

Comment: i will edit my code above so that you can see if i made anything wrong

Comment: Thankssssssssss I figured out what i was doing wrong , and your suggestion works perfectly :)))) Thankssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss!!!!!!! :)

Comment: Hi Again Arhimed. I want to ask you another question regarding the get cursor() function. I have 3 cursors in my main activity and used them to filter the 3 listviews i have. now after i use the get cursor in the getview in custom adapter , it only works with 1 listview. the other 2 are still not working. is there any way to get the cursor used to refresh or get it??

Comment: I forgot to tell you that i got the android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1 when opening any entry with the listview after applying the query filtering.

Comment: @Mohamed Hemdan: Please ask the new questions as new/separate StackOverflow questions providing details, code, etc. Feel free to post a link here - so if I have time I'll check them.